# How do I replace MPMoviePlayer notifications?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios9, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

In iOS 9 MPMoviePlayer and all his components are deprecated. 
We used MPMoviePlayerController notifications, like `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification, MPMovieDurationAvailableNotification, MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification, MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification`, to track video service quality. But now with AVPlayerViewController I can't find properly replacement for these notifications.

How do I replace these notifications now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AVPlayerViewController` is a lot different in its usage from the `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Instead of using notifications you use Key Value Observing to determine the current characteristics of the `AVPlayer` object associated with the `AVPlayerViewController`. According to the docs:

> You can observe the status of a player using key-value observing. So
>   that you can add and remove observers safely, AVPlayer serializes
>   notifications of changes that occur dynamically during playback on a
>   dispatch queue. By default, this queue is the main queue (see
>   dispatch_get_main_queue). To ensure safe access to a player’s
>   nonatomic properties while dynamic changes in playback state may be
>   reported, you must serialize access with the receiver’s notification
>   queue. In the common case, such serialization is naturally achieved by
>   invoking AVPlayer’s various methods on the main thread or queue.

For instance, if you want to know when your player has been paused add an observer on the `rate` property of the `AVPlayer` object:

```
[self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"rate" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context: &PlayerRateContext];
```

Then in the observe method check if the `new` value is equal to zero:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == &PlayerRateContext) {
        if ([[change valueForKey:@"new"] integerValue] == 0) {
            // summon Sauron here (or whatever you want to do)
        }
        return;
    }

    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    return;
}
```

A lot of properties on the `AVPlayer` are observable. Go through the [Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html).

Also apart from this there are several Notifications available for the `AVPlayerItem` object which are limited but still helpful.

> Notifications
>
> AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
>
> AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification
>
> AVPlayerItemTimeJumpedNotification
>
> AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalledNotification
>
> AVPlayerItemNewAccessLogEntryNotification
>
> AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntryNotification

I find `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` particularly useful to seek the Item to the start once playback has finished.

Using these two options together you should be able to replace most if not all notifications for the `MPMoviePlayerController`

Comment: Can you also provide a list of JWPlayer notifications? Unable to find a concise list on the net.

Comment: How do I convert MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification in AVPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the documentation for both `MPMoviePlayerNotifications` and `AVPlayerItemNotifications` and I notice two things.

1. [`MPMoviePlayerNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/) don't show they were deprecated:

   [image]
2. [`AVPlayerItemNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayerItem) don't have any replacements that I could see:

   [image]

So, I am confused that you are saying `MPMoviePlayerNotifications` are deprecated, because the docs are saying they are available. Also, I don't think `AVPlayerItemNotifications` has a replacement for `MPMoviePlayerNotifications`.

Comment: From documentation: `The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. (The MPMoviePlayerController class is also formally deprecated.) To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit`. I guess, that means no `MPMoviePlayerNotifications` notifications in future.