# Set UIActivityIndicatorView when AVPlayer is buffering? in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, buffer, avplayer

How can I check if my AVPlayer is buffering?

I want to detect if my AVPlayer is buffering for the .m3u8 format URl, so that I can show a loader or something when downloading video. But I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for AVPlayer.

Comment: find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845291/how-do-i-replace-mpmovieplayer-notifications,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030003/show-progress-bar-until-video-loads-ios7/24036738#24036738
use notification...

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVO to observe the keyPath `timeControlStatus`. There are three different statuses;

- `AVPlayerTimeControlStatusWaitingToPlayAtSpecifiedRate`
- `AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPlaying`
- `AVPlayerTimeControlStatusPaused`